# Projection (Datum?) slightly off for plotting Geopandas

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, datum, geopandas, folium

I'm trying to plot some polygons I obtained from a 2002 Census in Chile.
I'm loading them to `geopandas`, converting them to `epsg='4326'` and then sending them to `Folium` (which is a wrapper for `Leaflet`).

```
polygons = gpd.read_file('lim_polygon.shp')  
gjson = polygons.to_crs(epsg='4326').to_json()
my_map = folium.Map(location=[-33.45, -70.61], zoom_start=12)
```

[image: This is the result]

The real limits should be that red dotted line you see to the left of the polygons. This tells me the `to_crs` conversion is almost right, but off by about two or three blocks.

```
polygons.crs
```

gives

```
{'ellps': 'intl',
 'no_defs': True,
 'proj': 'utm',
 'south': True,
 'units': 'm',
 'zone': 19}
```

If I export the converted `json` and try it in `geojsonio` I get the same result, so I don't think it's an issue with `Leaflet` or `Folium`.

If it is that there's a different Datum.

How do I fix this?

[Here](http://wikisend.com/download/790978/polygons.zip) are the shapefiles in case you want to look at them

---

Does `'ellps': 'intl'` in the `crs` dictionary define a Datum?

`proj -ld` in the terminal gives me

```
nzgd49 intl         towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993
                          New Zealand Geodetic Datum 1949
```

`gdalsrsinfo lim_polygon.shp`, run in the terminal, gives me

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
PROJCS["User_Defined_UTM_Zone_19S",
    GEOGCS["GCS_User_Defined",
        DATUM["User_Defined",
            SPHEROID["User_Defined_Spheroid",6378388.0,297.0000000284015]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-69.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

Is Geopandas using that info to convert?

I read some documents that suggest that the data from Chile might be using either `SIRGAS` or `PSAD56`, but at this point I don't know how to convert datums (or declare a new `crs` in geopandas in case it was misspecified) to test if this would solve the issue.

Comment: You may be needing to reproject into Web Mercator (EPSG:3857) for the two to line up correctly, instead of WGS84 (EPSG:4326).

Comment: I tried EPSG:3857 but then I can't even see the polygons, it sends them somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the data and converted it to GeoJSON in WGS84 (EPSG:4326) using QGIS, and the data are in the wrong location still.

This leads me to believe that either the metadata on the dataset is wrong, and the CRS is different to what it says it is, or the data is wrong.

You should perhaps talk to the source of the data and ask about metadata. If the data is only this small area, you could simply shift them manually in a desktop GIS.

[image: Data transformed with QGIS and loaded with GeoJSON.io]

Comment: thanks! Can QGIS tell you what kind of Datum it's assuming the data has? I think the data is correct, but the Datum assumption is wrong

Comment: QGIS is saying it's a generic UTM, `+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a conversion from EPSG:28999 to WSG84.
I fixed it with adding a towgs84 key and value to the crs dictionary in python geopandas

```
    geo_df.crs['towgs84'] = '565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725'
```

and then covert it to WGS84

```
    geo_df= geo_df.to_crs(epsg=4326)
```

It looks like your file has an EPSG:24879 coordinate system: https://epsg.io/24879

The PROJ.4 definition has this towgs84 value `+towgs84=-288,175,-376,0,0,0,0`

So update your dataframe crs as follows:

```
    geo_df.crs['towgs84'] = '-288,175,-376,0,0,0,0'
```

And then change the projection to wgs84.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Unfortunately I don't have the shapefiles with me anymore, but this "towgs84" method seems like it could do the trick. I'll try to get the shapefiles again and come back to comment